# How can I create a function with a tuple as the parameter and then find the sum of the integers in the tuple without using sum()?

Tags: python

As the title suggests I'm lost on how to add the integers in a tuple together without using the sum() function. I think I need to iterate over the tuple itself, but I'm not entirely sure. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: SO is not a free coding or homework service. Please read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and associated documents to understand what is and isn't appropriate on this site. This does not appear to be your first unpopular question.

Comment: Do it the same way as if the tuple was a list. This is something you can google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya your approach of iterating over the tuple is correct.
The code:

```
def sum_of_tuple(tupl):
    su_m = 0
    for i in tupl:
        su_m += 
    return su_m
```

That snippet returns the sum perfectly.